# Is it possible to populate a field entity reference with query parameters?

Tags: views, entities

I created an entity reference field for a node filtered by a view type "entity reference", but I need to pass an argument in the contextual filter of this view, to filter entities on my field.

I tried passing my argument on the URL in a query parameter (e.g. node/add/page_interieur?dossier=2), but I never get results in my field autocomplete.

Is it possible to do that with this method or another one?

#### Settings for the contextual filter with the *Query parameter* option

> [image: screenshot]

#### Settings for the *Entity reference* field

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To programmatically pass argument to my field entity reference with link `node/add/page_interieur?dossier=512` :

```
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

function my_module_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id){

  if ($form_id == 'node_page_interieur_form') {
    $nid  = \Drupal::request()->query->get('dossier');

    if (is_numeric($nid) && isset($form['field_dossier_reference'])) {
      //autocomplete select field reference
      $form['field_dossier_reference']['widget']['#default_value'] = $nid;
      //disable field
      $form['field_dossier_reference']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
      //pass my ID like argument in my field to filter only pages referenced
      $form['field_liste_ref_dossier']['widget']['target_id']['#selection_settings']['view']['arguments'][] = $nid;
    }

    foreach (array_keys($form['actions']) as $action) {
      if ($action != 'preview' && isset($form['actions'][$action]['#type']) && $form['actions'][$action]['#type'] === 'submit') {
        $form['actions'][$action]['#submit'][] = 'science_po_page_interieur_form_submit';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My contextual filter configuration in views :[image]

Comment: Not working any more. Tested with Drupal 8.9.

Answer (score -1):

**For** example.com/path?id=55

[current-page:query:id]

**For** example.com/path/55

[current-page:url:args:last]

**For** example.com/path/alias

[current-page:url:unaliased:args:last]